# How to change data type of element JSON?

Tags: android, arrays, json, object, kotlin

i found an issue with my API, the issue is there is different data type in JSON, how i can change the result with array type to array object with **kotlin** lang? below is the example issue. thank you

```
User: [{
       Result : {},
       Result : {},
       Result : []
}]
```

and here is my supported class for call the API

```
class ServiceFactory {
    private fun retrofit(): Retrofit {
        val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()

    }

    fun instanceServices(): Services {
        return retrofit().create(Services::class.java)
    }
}
```

PRESENTER

```
class JobsPresenter(private val view: JobsView) {

    fun getAllJobs(){
        view.showLoading()
        val api = ServiceFactory().instanceServices().getJobs()
        api.enqueue(object : Callback<JobsModel>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<JobsModel>, t: Throwable) {
                view.hideLoading()
                view.onFailure(t)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<JobsModel>, response: Response<JobsModel>) {
                view.hideLoading()
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    view.onResponse(response.body())
                }
            }

        })
    }
}
```

This presenter triggered from Fragment

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        getJobs()
    }

    private fun getJobs() {
        JobsPresenter(this).getAllJobs()
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit further? How does your class look like?

Comment: please check updated my question above @Adam Arold